# EF Core - How to Configure Column Type depending on the Database Provider used

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Each database providers have different data types that would map to the same C# types (Guid / DateTime)

I want to configure the column types depending on the database provider used.

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

If Sql Server is used

- Configure `DateTime` as `datetime2(0)`

If MySql Server is used

- Configure `DateTime` as `TIMESTAMP`
- Configure `Guid` as `CHAR(36)`

So, I'm looking for code similar to below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if(IsSqlServer)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
            .Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
            .HasColumnType("datetime2(0)")
            ;
    }
    else if(IsMySqlServer) 
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
            .Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
            .HasColumnType("TIMESTAMP")
            ;

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
            .Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnType("CHAR(36)")
            ;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do so in EF Core? (Latest stable 3.1 as time of writing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the DbContext, you can use `this.Database.ProviderName`

```cs
if (this.Database.ProviderName == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
        .Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
        .HasColumnType("datetime2(0)")
        ;
}
```

Some providers also include extension methods to help with that

```cs
if (this.Database.IsSqlServer())
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
        .Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
        .HasColumnType("datetime2(0)")
        ;
}
```

Comment: It is usually easier to use a sugar method such as `Database.IsSqlServer()` instead. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/3bd012b6dc645f6d4e14ddb473c42f3fa4e0b98b/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/DatabaseFacade.cs#L310-L312

Comment: How about when we are inside an `IEntityTypeConfiguration<ModelType>` class?