# DataAnnotation for fixedLength in Entity Framework Core on .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, annotations

I'm using .NET 6 and EF Core with code-first approach.

```cs
public class MyObj 
{
    [MaxLength(7)]
    public string MyField { get; set; }
}
```

With `[MaxLength(7)]` I can create a migration with the `maxLength` parameter:

```cs
table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 7, nullable: false)
```

I also want to say to EF Core that `MyField` is made up of at least 7 characters => fixed length.

Some questions:

1. Is there a DataAnnotation attribute for fixedLength like `[MaxLength(7)]` for max length?
2. How does knowing that a string has a fixed length affect the database?

Edit:

@Steve in a comment under this question propose `[Column(TypeName="Char(7)")]` that produce

```cs
table.Column<string>(type: "Char(7)", nullable: false),
```

In this case with `"Char(7)"` I'm directly use a SQL keyword, right?

So, in my case it works, but as I saw [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli), EF Core can also work with NoSQL database; will `"Char(7)"` be a problem in that case?

Comment: Not tried, but the attribute Column has a TypeName property where you can specify the datatype to use on the db. You can try with _[Column("MyField", TypeName="Char(7)")]_

Comment: Or perhaps _[Column("MyField", TypeName="CHAR")]_ and _[MaxLength(7)]_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core - How to Configure Column Type depending on the Database Provider used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62916893/ef-core-how-to-configure-column-type-depending-on-the-database-provider-used)

Answer (score 0):

use `StringLength`

```
  [StringLength(7, ErrorMessage = "The MyField value cannot exceed 7 characters. ")]
  public string MyField { get; set; }
```

Comment: As I read form the [Entity Framework Core site](https://entityframeworkcore.com/model-data-annotations) the StringLengthAttribute has the same functionality of MaxLengthAttribute, but only for strings. I have already tried it, and the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use both MinLengh attribute and MaxLengh Attribute to achieve the result you're after

[MinLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute?view=net-6.0)